# Setup SipSorcery Server

Tags: c#, sip, voip, sip-server

I am new in SIP Programming, while searching on Google "**voip sdk c# open source github**", I got reference of ***sipsorcery***. I had downloaded it and try to play with samples but I am unable to execute it. I had search tutorials on google and youtube but I can't found any.

https://github.com/sipsorcery/sipsorcery

Please someone guide if I have to implement sipsorcery (Video and Audio Call) then How can I setup Server, which support to multiple client.

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 2):

Best way to get started are the example applications:

- [Get Started Audio](https://github.com/sipsorcery/sipsorcery/tree/master/examples/SIPExamples/GetStarted),
- [Get Started Video](https://github.com/sipsorcery/sipsorcery/tree/master/examples/SIPExamples/GetStartedVideo) you will need something to call such as [MicroSIP](https://www.microsip.org/).

All the examples are .NET Core or Framework applications and can be generally be executed from the command line with `dotnet run`. If you have problems with them, or the library, I'd recommend the asking on the [GitHub Issues page](https://github.com/sipsorcery/sipsorcery/issues).

Also note that the `sipsorcery` project is library not a Server application. It can be used to build server applications but the only ones available in the repo are examples.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.

Comment: @AaronClauson can you please help me here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65653678/converting-sip2-request-to-web-api-request-and-web-api-response-to-sip2-response

Comment: Is this still open source? I found this and not sure it's the same https://www.sipsorcery.com/mainsite