# Converting SIP2(Standard Interchange Protocol) Request to Web API Request and web API Response to SIP2 Response

Tags: c#, .net, sip, sip-server

We have a requirement from one of our clients. They had in-built library management system(LMS) in .net c# and have API's to interact with LMS. Recently they introduced KIOSK and RFID system in library for issue, submit etc. of books through KIOSK in library.

So currently as per vendor KIOSK will make SIP2 call(Request) to IP configured(server), based on each SIP KISOK SIP2 Request we can map web API and response from that web API will be again sent to KIOSK as SIP2 Response.

So my query is how to listen to SIP2 Request made by KIOSK and respond using C#. Do I need to install SIP-server ? Can we create SIP Request listener/server using some .net library ?

Can we use Koha as reverse proxy server ?

Comment: Here's a demo of listening for SIP requests in .NET Core https://github.com/sipsorcery/sipsorcery/blob/master/examples/SIPExamples/SIPProxy/Program.cs. It depends on what you need to do with the SIP messages as to whether you need a fully fledged SIP server or not.

Comment: I tried using this(https://github.com/sipsorcery-org/sipsorcery/blob/master/examples/SIPExamples/SIPProxy/Program.cs) along with SIP2 client (https://github.com/NiceAndNerdy/SIP2.NET). I was able to connect to server but when I tried sending SIP2 Request from client I was unable to receive same on server end. 
One more question can I use this server to implement SIP2 for LMS as explained here https://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.556.541&rep=rep1&type=pdf

Comment: The SIP protocol I was referring to (and that the SIP tag corresponds to) is the Session Initiation Protocol. The SIP2.NET and the other link you've provided seem to be referring to a Standard Interchange Protocol, which is completely different.

Comment: thank you clearing the confusion